# My ClickHouse Server suddenly stopped allowing connection

Tags: database, bigdata, clickhouse

I was working with clickhouse-server and clickhouse-client to connect to clickhouse-server on my localhost, it was going fine, but suddenly it stopped connection, i mean now when i try to connect using sudo clickhouse-client --password=xxxxxx i get the following error

```
ClickHouse client version 19.16.3.6 (official build).
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9000)
```

i also tried to change ::1 to :: in listen_host tag in config.
Any help please

Comment: probably CH server has been killed by OOM killer

Comment: but server is running, just client not connecting to it

Comment: look at the log-files: *var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log*

Answer (score -1):

Ok finally i solved it myself :) i simply commented out listen_host tags, deleted status file, started server again and it works now .. thanks everyone.